# How do I solve materialise nav-bar issues?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, materialize

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu in my nav bar using materialise, but it's not working. I'm adding the code snippet. In addition to this, I have imported materialise CSS and icons in the head, as well as the JS and JQuery in the body.

Can someone help me with where I'm going wrong? This is the documentation https://materializecss.com/navbar.html#!

```
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="./music/index.html">Bollywood Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="./OTT/index.html">OTT TV Series</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Academic Literature</a></li>
        <li><a href="./yaFiction/index.html">YA Fiction</a></li>
    </ul>
         
    <nav class="nav-wraper #362b32">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class= "right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Articles<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!--JQuery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the class names are correct. The class `nav-wraper` in the `<nav>` [should be](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html) `nav-wrapper`, not `nav-wraper`.

As for the dropdown, the code is initializing the dropdown for the class `dropdown-trigger`, but the HTML uses `dropdown-button`. Change `class="dropdown-button"` to `class="dropdown-trigger"`.

The [documentation](https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html) also states that the correct attribute for specifying the ID of the dropdown target is `data-target`, but the HTML uses `data-activates`, so change that.

Finally, JQuery should be loaded *before* Materialize, so that Materialize can register the `.dropdown()` function with JQuery.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="./music/index.html">Bollywood Music</a></li>
    <li><a href="./OTT/index.html">OTT TV Series</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Academic Literature</a></li>
    <li><a href="./yaFiction/index.html">YA Fiction</a></li>
  </ul>

  <nav class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#" data-target="dropdown1">
          Articles<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
        </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!--JQuery-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```